# Join plan node with condition=true encounter an error

Tags: apache-calcite

```
final RelBuilder builder = RelBuilder.create(config().build());
    RelNode root =
        builder.scan("EMP")
            .as("e")
            .scan("EMP")
            .as("m")
            .scan("DEPT")
            .join(JoinRelType.INNER)
            .join(JoinRelType.INNER)
            .filter(
                builder.equals(builder.field("e", "DEPTNO"),
                    builder.field("DEPT", "DEPTNO")),
                builder.equals(builder.field("m", "EMPNO"),
                    builder.field("e", "MGR")))
            .build();
    final String expected = ""
        + "LogicalFilter(condition=[AND(=($7, $16), =($8, $3))])\n"
        + "  LogicalJoin(condition=[true], joinType=[inner])\n"
        + "    LogicalTableScan(table=[[scott, EMP]])\n"
        + "    LogicalJoin(condition=[true], joinType=[inner])\n"
        + "      LogicalTableScan(table=[[scott, EMP]])\n"
        + "      LogicalTableScan(table=[[scott, DEPT]])\n";
    assertThat(str(root), is(expected));
```

The code above is from RelBuilderTest.java 。why does calcite generate the `LogicalJoin(condition=[true], joinType=[inner])` Node? when I use `RelToSqlConverter` to convert the RelNode to SQL,it encounter an error about the `filter 'condition=[true]'`

```
ava.lang.AssertionError: Internal error: While invoking method 'public org.apache.calcite.rel.rel2sql.SqlImplementor$Result org.apache.calcite.rel.rel2sql.RelToSqlConverter.visit(org.apache.calcite.rel.core.Filter)
at org.apache.calcite.util.Util.newInternal(Util.java:792)
at org.apache.calcite.util.ReflectUtil$2.invoke(ReflectUtil.java:535)
at org.apache.calcite.rel.rel2sql.RelToSqlConverter.dispatch(RelToSqlConverter.java:80
```

why does this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RelBuilder` is doing what is told: building a join with no condition. This is analogous to how you might write

```
SELECT ...
FROM Emp, Dept
```

and later specify the join condition in the `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE Emp.deptno = Dept.deptno
```

`RelBuilder` doesn't try to make optimizations (aside from a few micro-optimizations like removing trivial `Project`s). Folding the `Filter` onto the `Join` is the job of `FilterIntoJoinRule`, and will duly happen during the query optimization phase.

The error in `RelToSqlConverter` is a [known issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CALCITE-1792) and will be fixed in the next release (1.13.0).